# PUT request 404 not found error Postman? Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

When trying to make a PUT request to update a house for my MERN application. The route does not seem to work on the server-side, in postman it shows a 404 not found error. I have speculation that it may be the way my routes are set up because it does not even recognize the that I am trying to make a PUT request. All of my other routes work but for some reason I am getting the index.html Error in postman. The PUT request is at the bottom of the HouseList Route code.

HouseList Route

```
// const express = require('express')
// const router = express.Router()
const router = require('express').Router();
const {House} = require('../../Models/House');
const Formidable = require('formidable');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require("dotenv").config()
// const { request, response } = require('express');
// const dotenv = require("dotenv");


// dotenv.config();


//mongoDB and Cloudinary

const mongoURI = process.env.Mongo_URI;

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
})


mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}, (error)=>{
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }
    return console.log("database is connected")
})

router.post("/api/house-listing", async (request, response)=>{
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(request, (error, fields, files)=>{
        const {
            price,
            city,
            county,
            numOfBeds,
            numOfBaths,
            numOfGarages,
            isSaleOrRent,
            us_state,
            squarefeet
        } = fields

        const { house_image } = files;

        console.log('Price: ', price)
        console.log('City: ', city)
        console.log('county: ', county)
        console.log('state: ', us_state)
        console.log('squarefeet', squarefeet)
        console.log('numOfGarages: ', numOfGarages)
        console.log('numOfBeds: ', numOfBeds)
        console.log('numOfBaths: ', numOfBaths)
        console.log('isSaleOrRent: ', isSaleOrRent)
        console.log('houseImage', house_image.path)

        cloudinary.uploader.upload( house_image.path, 
            {folder:"/houseAgency/houses"}, async(error, result)=>{
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            const image_url = result.url;

            const newHouse = new House({
                house_location: {
                    
                    county: county,
                    city: city,
                    us_state: us_state
                   

                },

                house_details: {
                    price: price,
                    squarefeet: squarefeet,
                    numOfBeds: numOfBeds,
                    numOfBaths: numOfBaths,
                    numOfGarages: numOfGarages,
                    isSaleOrRent: isSaleOrRent,
                    house_image: image_url,
                }
            })
            const savedHouse = await newHouse.save();
            return response.status(200).json(savedHouse)
        })
    })
})

router.put('/api/house-details/:id', (req, res) => {
    House.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body).exec().then((data)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        if (data === null) {
           return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "house-details", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
        }
        return res.status(200).json(data)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        return res.status(500).json({"error": error})
    })
});




module.exports = router;
```

HouseFetch

```
// const express= require('express')

// const router = express.Router()
const router = require('express').Router();

const {House} = require('../../Models/House');



//HOUSE Fetch


router.get('/api/house-sale', async(req, res)=>{

    try{
        House.find({'house_details.isSaleOrRent': 'SALE'}).exec().then((data)=>{
            // console.log(data);
            return res.status(200).json(data)
        })
    } catch(error) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: 'server is currently Down :('})
    }
   
})


router.get('/api/house-rent', async(req, res)=>{

    try{
        House.find({'house_details.isSaleOrRent': 'RENT'}).exec().then((data)=>{
            return res.status(200).json(data)
        })
    } catch(error) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: 'server is currently Down :('})
    }
   
})


router.get('/api/house-details/:id', async(req, res)=>{

    await House.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec().then(data=>{

        return res.status(200).json(data)
    }).catch(error =>{
        return res.status(400).json(error)
    })
})




router.get("/api/house-search/:query", async (request, response) => {
    const us_states = [
      "Alabama", "Alaska", "American Samoa", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Minor Outlying Islands", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "U.S. Virgin Islands", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"
    ];

    
    const query = request.params.query;
  
    const result = [];
    for (let counter = 0; counter < us_states.length; counter++) {
      let currentStates = us_states[counter];
      if (query.toLowerCase().includes(currentStates.toLowerCase())) {
        result.push(currentStates);
      }
    }
  
    House.find({ "house_location.us_state": result[0] })
      .exec()
      .then((data) => {
        return response.status(200).json(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });

 

 
  
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you missing the `/api` part of your route? `/api/house-details/:id`

Comment: I was but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You will get 404 for any error during House.findByIdAndUpdate, does the body with update data match the mongoose schema model? Try to log body an error, and compare body with your schema.

Comment: The request gives me a 200 status code now but none of the data actually updates. I tried to log the body. but it doesn't look like I'm getting any of the data.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `async/await` and `.then .catch` together, use `async/await` with `try/catch`, and you don't need to return when you use `res` so you should update all queries like this:

```
try {
    let data = await House.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body).toObject()
    res.status(200).json(data)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({"error": error})
}
```

if you want result of find be a plain object javascript you can use `lean()` for `find` and use `toObject` for `findOne` or `findById` also you can try like this

```
let data = await House.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body)
res.status(200).json({data})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute the method put in a route but you have not declared it in your code.
In your question you do not mention what route you are trying to access. I suppose you would like to do a put in route `/api/house-details/:id`.

In order to achieve this, you should declare a new route with [put](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) method, after put route declaration you should write your route handler:

```
router.put('/api/house-details/:id', (req, res) => {
    const options = { new: true };
    House.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, options).exec().then((data)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        if (data.value === null) {
           return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "house-details", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
        }
        return res.status(200).json(data)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        return res.status(500).json({"error": error})
    })
});
```

To return the modified the modified collection item (after update), you must include `options: { new: true}`, as stated by [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: that was my mistake  I was adding new code to an edit on the post and forgot to include the route when copying and pasting. But I tried your suggestion and while I get a 200 status code the body does not update the data in postman. why could this be happening?

Comment: just add: `{new: true}` as a parameter in function `findByIdAndUpdate` and it will return the modified element.

Comment: Ok so I tried added this new piece of code but it still only returns the old body without the updated values.

Comment: Can you check if the value is updated with new values in mongodb shell?

Comment: The values did not update in the mongo shell. it logs the body of the changed value but it does not actually change the value

Comment: Can you try change filter, you can put: just the id, i will fix answer. Change to: `House.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, options)`

Comment: Thank you for all your help that worked that values update in postman and mongodb, but the only weird thing is when I do it the actual object deletes itself from the application and doesn't show up after running the postman request even though it is still in the database.

Comment: After you do a update you can do a get again to list all items from database. I think it is not related to the original question.  Maybe it is another problem.

Comment: yea i believe so after trying to refresh in the browser it looks like all the values that weren't updated come back as undefined might be something with the client-side.